# Visual Studio 2017: can't create help project

Tags: visual-studio

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2017 (the free version) & want to add help files to a project. Microsoft's help says I need to create a help project, & to do this I should "create a new project" & "follow the instructions 
". I presume there's supposed to be a project template for help projects, but I  can't find one. Is there a component I'm supposed to install? I've searched through the ones available from the Installer, but can't find anything that would be helpful. Thanks...

Comment: you are trying to create a Read me file in your project?

Comment: Help authoring tools went the way of the dodo.  Everybody uses a web page these days.  The HTML Help Workshop is still available as a separate download.

Comment: That's me, a stuck-in-the-past dodo. But if it's not available, why does Microsoft say that I should be able to create a help project?

Comment: Also, I'm a  hobby programmer, not a professional - I don't have a server to host a web page